# Receive an error after clicking carousel item

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

We have an action running in production just fine. It has just started returning an error after trying to click or invoke an item from a carousel.

Steps to reproduce are as follows

1. Talk to Action
2. Carosel loads fine
3. Invoke any item in Carousel via click or voice
4. receive the error

Sorry, {action} is not responding at this time. Please try again later.

Here is a snippet of how it is being built.

There is nothing reported as an error in stackdriver logs

```
  /**
   * @description Build the Carousel
   * @private
   * @static
   * @param {CardListItem[]} listItems - Array of CardListItem to transform
   * @returns {Carousel}
   * Returns a Carousel
   * @memberof TemplateBuilder
   */
  private static getCarousel(listItems: CardListItem[]): Carousel {
    const items = [] as GoogleActionsV2UiElementsCarouselSelectCarouselItem[];
    listItems = this.sortListTemplateListItemsByGoogleIndexAscending(listItems);
    for (const listItem of listItems) {
      if (listItem.googleIndex) {
        items.push(this.getCarouselItem(listItem));
      }
    }
    return new Carousel({
      items,
      display: 'DEFAULT',
    });
  }

  /**
   * @description Build a CarouselItem
   * @private
   * @static
   * @param {CardListItem} data - Template data of type ListTemplateData
   * @returns {GoogleActionsV2UiElementsCarouselSelectCarouselItem}
   * Returns a Carousel Item
   * @memberof TemplateBuilder
   */
  private static getCarouselItem(data: CardListItem): GoogleActionsV2UiElementsCarouselSelectCarouselItem {
    const title = data.textContent ? this.convertToPlainText(data.textContent) : null;
    const imageUrl = typeof data.image === 'string' ? data.image : data.image.imageUrl;
    return {
      optionInfo: {
        key: data.intentHandler || data.token,
        synonyms: [],
      } as GoogleActionsV2OptionInfo,
      image: new Image({
        url: this.getImageURL(imageUrl),
        alt: title,
        height: null,
        width: null,
      }),
      title,
    } as GoogleActionsV2UiElementsCarouselSelectCarouselItem;
  }
```

Response from the web hook

```
{
    "payload": {
      "google": {
        "expectUserResponse": true,
        "systemIntent": {
          "intent": "actions.intent.OPTION",
          "data": {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.OptionValueSpec",
            "carouselSelect": {
              "items": [
                {
                  "optionInfo": {
                    "key": "AccountBalanceIntent",
                    "synonyms": []
                  },
                  "image": {
                    "url": "https://aglvoiceprod.blob.core.windows.net/images/google/thumb-account.jpg",
                    "accessibilityText": "Account Balance",
                    "height": null,
                    "width": null
                  },
                  "title": "Account Balance"
                },
                {
                  "optionInfo": {
                    "key": "UsageCostIntent",
                    "synonyms": []
                  },
                  "image": {
                    "url": "https://aglvoiceprod.blob.core.windows.net/images/google/thumb-usage.jpg",
                    "accessibilityText": "Energy Usage",
                    "height": null,
                    "width": null
                  },
                  "title": "Energy Usage"
                },
                {
                  "optionInfo": {
                    "key": "BillAmountIntent",
                    "synonyms": []
                  },
                  "image": {
                    "url": "https://aglvoiceprod.blob.core.windows.net/images/google/thumb-bill.jpg",
                    "accessibilityText": "Bill History",
                    "height": null,
                    "width": null
                  },
                  "title": "Bill History"
                },
                {
                  "optionInfo": {
                    "key": "EnergyInsightsIntent",
                    "synonyms": []
                  },
                  "image": {
                    "url": "https://aglvoiceprod.blob.core.windows.net/images/google/thumb-insights.jpg",
                    "accessibilityText": "Energy Insights",
                    "height": null,
                    "width": null
                  },
                  "title": "Energy Insights"
                },
                {
                  "optionInfo": {
                    "key": "BillDueDateIntent",
                    "synonyms": []
                  },
                  "image": {
                    "url": "https://aglvoiceprod.blob.core.windows.net/images/google/thumb-bill-due-date.jpg",
                    "accessibilityText": "Bill Due Date",
                    "height": null,
                    "width": null
                  },
                  "title": "Bill Due Date"
                },
                {
                  "optionInfo": {
                    "key": "EnergyAlertIntent",
                    "synonyms": []
                  },
                  "image": {
                    "url": "https://aglvoiceprod.blob.core.windows.net/images/google/thumb-alert.jpg",
                    "accessibilityText": "Energy Alert",
                    "height": null,
                    "width": null
                  },
                  "title": "Energy Alert"
                },
                {
                  "optionInfo": {
                    "key": "EnergyTipIntent",
                    "synonyms": []
                  },
                  "image": {
                    "url": "https://aglvoiceprod.blob.core.windows.net/images/google/thumb-tip.jpg",
                    "accessibilityText": "Energy Tip",
                    "height": null,
                    "width": null
                  },
                  "title": "Energy Tip"
                }
              ],
              "imageDisplayOptions": "DEFAULT"
            }
          }
        },
        "richResponse": {
          "items": [
            {
              "simpleResponse": {
                "textToSpeech": "<speak>Hi Brent,<break time=\"200ms\"/> welcome to <say-as interpret-as=\"spell-out\">AGL</say-as>.<break time=\"400ms\"/> With our latest update,<break time=\"200ms\"/> you can now set up Energy Alerts.<break time=\"300ms\"/> For other ways that I can help,<break time=\"200ms\"/> say \"more information\".<break time=\"350ms\"/> How can I help you today?</speak>",
                "displayText": "Hi Brent, welcome to AGL. With our latest update, you can now set up Energy Alerts. For other ways that I can help, say \"more information\". How can I help you today?"
              }
            }
          ],
          "suggestions": [
            {
              "title": "Monthly Billing"
            },
            {
              "title": "eBilling"
            },
            {
              "title": "Payment Extension"
            },
            {
              "title": "Feedback"
            },
            {
              "title": "Help"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/agl-prod-603de/agent/sessions/ABwppHESxXC8wRCVt2-hskWfsZwxEoH54G6jm_yTj2oIiETa1V3EbgRGj86H7Ys5bEKG0YrzkL0fE9Mpnhk/contexts/_actions_on_google",
        "lifespanCount": 99,
        "parameters": {
          "data": "{\"sessionLaunched\":true,\"skippedIntents\":[],\"possibleIntents\":[],\"followUp\":{\"yes\":{\"data\":null,\"intent\":\"Unhandled\"},\"no\":{\"data\":null,\"intent\":\"Unhandled\"},\"fuelType\":{\"elec\":{\"data\":null,\"intent\":\"Unhandled\"},\"gas\":{\"data\":null,\"intent\":\"Unhandled\"},\"both\":{\"data\":null,\"intent\":\"Unhandled\"}},\"number\":{\"data\":null,\"intent\":\"Unhandled\",\"slotName\":null},\"period\":{\"data\":null,\"intent\":\"Unhandled\",\"slotName\":null}},\"lastIntent\":\"LaunchRequest\"}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

[flow in simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzSVn.jpg)
[image: touch event hander dialogflow]

Comment: Are you using the handler for click event for carousels? https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/selection-responses#df-nodejs-caro-selected

Comment: yes we are watching for the option event we have it hooked up in dialogflow posted the imaged and we deal with the event in the code with a touch event handler. This has been working perfectly fine for the past few months and only recently in past few days  started failing

Comment: Were you able to resolve this or you're still experiencing the same issue?

In order for me to further understand the problem, there're a few things i'd need, 

For example, the lower half of the Dialogflow screenshot because im unable to see if that intent has the webhook enabled?
Make sure debugging is enabled using the following code snippet
const app = dialogflow({ debug: true });
This will log both the request and response payload when the user clicks the option in the carousel

Look into the firebase logs, you should be to see the request and response.